# Firebase Firestore Design

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firestore database especially document related database. I have the following structure format as show below. Is it a good structure? as seen below the subcollection userinfo will have only 1 document to store the user's information.

```
/users (collection)
  /userId1 (document)
    /userinfo (subcollection)
      /documentId1 (document)
        - name: "John Doe"
        - email: "john@example.com"
    /address (subcollection)
      /documentId2 (document)
        - street: "123 Main St"
        - city: "Example City"
  /userId2 (document)
    /userinfo (subcollection)
      /documentId3 (document)
        - name: "Jane Doe"
        - email: "jane@example.com"
    /address (subcollection)
      /documentId4 (document)
        - street: "456 Oak St"
        - city: "Another City"
```

I have the above structure, but I feel like it's not optimised, coming from someone who usually use SQL Database.

Comment: Data models in NoSQL evolve to meet the requirements of your app. So there's no "good" or "bad", rather the data model either allows you to implement your use-case(s) or it doesn't. To get started with this, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching Todd's excellent: [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries? Please respond using @AlexMamo